# how to change the position of the output result in GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, position

Does any one here have an idea about how to change the position of output in the GUI matlab to be to the right side of the box and not in the center ?

i think I have to change some properties of the result text box

Comment: What have you tried? Any plot, code matrix you could show us? Is it like you add a figure/shape then you position it? In what context are you asking this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check this post out: [Positioning of figures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/positioning-figures.html)

The figure Position property controls the size and location of the figure window on the screen. Monitor screen size is a property of the root Handle Graphics object. At startup, the MATLAB software determines the size of your computer screen and defines a default value for Position. This default creates figures about one-quarter of the screen's minimum extent and places them centered left to right, in the top half of the screen.
The Position Vector

MATLAB defines the figure Position property as a vector. So you may use a figure and text into it, e.g.

```
figure(gcf)
text(offsetX1, offsetX1, ['result 1: ' num2str(result1)])
text(offsetX2, offsetX2, ['result 2: ' num2str(result2)])
```

- [Displaying analytical results in a MATLAB GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964268/displaying-analytical-results-in-a-matlab-gui)
  This post talks about adding a static textbox with your results and positioning it.
- [Move GUI figure to specified location on screen:](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movegui.html)

Syntax:

```
movegui(h,'position')
movegui(position)
movegui(h)
movegui
```

***The answer is pretty much trying to cover up the vauge nature of the question***

Comment: @Gloria how did it go? Is your problem solved fully? Let us know if you have more questions, happy to help :)